# Issue in this SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have three textboxes in my webpage with autocomplete using html5 datalist tag. Now i want to display search results when user clicks on search button.

How to take all three textbox box field values and search in one SQL query to display similar results in another page..

**HTML:**

```
<form class="tg-formtheme tg-formsearch">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search Thousands of verified business</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" list="city" placeholder="Enter city">
    </div>
    <datalist id="city">
              <option value="Bangalore">
              <option value="hyderabad">
                  <option value="mumbai">
              <option value="pune">
              <option value="chennai">
              <option value="kolkata">
              <option value="jaipur">
              <option value="delhi">
              <option value="kanput">
              <option value="indore">
              <option value="patna">
              <option value="mysore">
    </datalist>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" list="location" placeholder="Enter location">
    </div>
    <datalist id="location">
              <option value="Marathahalli">
              <option value="BTM Layout">
                  <option value="HSR Layout">
              <option value="Banashankari">
              <option value="Basavanagudi">
              <option value="Domlur">
              <option value="Jayanagar">
              <option value="Koramangala">
              <option value="Rajajinagar">
              <option value="Sadashivanagar">
              <option value="Nagarbhavi">
              <option value="Whitefield">
    </datalist>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="select Category">
    </div>

    <div class="tg-btns">
        <button class="tg-btn" type="submit">Search Now</button>
        <button class="tg-btn" type="submit">Reset all</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){


$city = trim($_POST['city']);
$location = trim($_POST['location']);
$category  = trim($_POST['category']);



  $stmt = $search->runQuery("SELECT * FROM jposts WHERE city LIKE %'.$city.'% OR location LIKE %'.$location.'% OR business_name LIKE %'.$category.'%");
 $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 
        extract($row);
        echo $row['city'] . "<br>";
        echo $row['business_name'];
        echo $row['address'];
    
 }
```

After submitting the data, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'. tirupati .'% OR location LIKE %'. amnagar .'% OR business_name LIKE %'. maci' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\justshow.in\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\justshow.in\index.php(20): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\justshow.in\index.php on line 20
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, what are your results? what you should do is: get the post data, use that data in your SQL query. In the WHERE clause you can use LIKE

Comment: which values do you mean? The autocomplete values or the values in the text-inputs?

Comment: values in the textbox where user selects using autocomplete functionality

Comment: what is wrong with your PHP-Code? Does something not work?

Comment: it shows....fatal error syntax voilation

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'. tirupati .'% OR location LIKE %'. amnagar .'% OR business_name LIKE %'. maci' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\justshow.in\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\justshow.in\index.php(20): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\justshow.in\index.php on line 20

Comment: For the next time: if you have an error - post it. This is a very valuable piece of information in such a case.

Comment: The error clearly states it's an error in your sql. The only code you probably need to post is your sql. Maybe php, but the HTML completely irrelevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Syntax-Error in your Query using the [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)-Operator. You have to use the precent-char inside of quotes like this:

```
"... WHERE city LIKE '%".$city."' OR ...
```

The final Query should look like this:

```
... WHERE city LIKE '%mumbai' OR ...
```

Check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) link for more information about LIKE.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for...but i want to be search three texbox values in sql query and display results

Comment: there's no difference when you use three `input`-Fields, you can use as many as you want - just give them different `name`-Values. To display the result, check this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_select_query.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your ticks are not placed correctly. Try this:

```
 $stmt = $search->runQuery("SELECT * FROM jposts WHERE city LIKE '%".$city."%' 
  OR location LIKE '%".$location."%' OR business_name LIKE 
 '%".$category."%'");
```